# Summation of results from a loop

Tags: python, function, loops, sum

I would like to be able to calculate the sum of the 'totalTimes' that is returned by the loop. Any ideas on how to do it? Here is the code I currently have:

Thanks

```
subjectsNum = int(input ("How many subjects do you have to study?"))

def subject():
    for i in range (1, subjectsNum+1):

        subjectName = input ("What is the subject name?")
        pagesQuantity = float(input ("How many pages do you have to study?"))
        pagesTime = float (input ("How long do you reckon it will take to study one page (in minutes)?"))
        totalTime = (pagesQuantity) * (pagesTime)/60
        print("The estimated time to study %s is %s hours" %(subjectName, totalTime) )


subject()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just have an accumulator list outside the loop.

```
def subject():
    times = []  # this is our accumulator
    for i in range(1, subjectsNum+1):
        ...
        times.append(totalTime)

    return times  # return it to the outer scope

times = subject()  # assign the return value to a variable
grand_total = sum(times)  # then add it up.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an extra variable, which you set to zero before, and add to it in the loop.

```
def subject(subjectsNum):
    totalSum = 0
    for i in range (subjectsNum):

        subjectName = input ("What is the subject name?")
        pagesQuantity = float(input ("How many pages do you have to study?"))
        pagesTime = float (input ("How long do you reckon it will take to study one page (in minutes)?"))
        totalTime = (pagesQuantity) * (pagesTime)/60
        print("The estimated time to study {} is {} hours".format(subjectName, totalTime) )
        totalSum += totalTime
    return totalSum


subjectsNum = int(input ("How many subjects do you have to study?"))
totalSum = subject(subjectsNum)
print("Sum is {}".format(totalSum))
```

By the way, I also made `subjectsNum` a parameter to `subject()`, and used the new-style `format` function, and looped `i` over [0,n-1] instead of [1,n].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the return value of for loop you have to save the result somewhere and at last just sum the all result.

```
subjectsNum = int(input ("How many subjects do you have to study?"))

Final_total_time=[]

def subject():
    for i in range (1, subjectsNum+1):

        subjectName = input ("What is the subject name?")
        pagesQuantity = float(input ("How many pages do you have to study?"))
        pagesTime = float (input ("How long do you reckon it will take to study one page (in minutes)?"))
        totalTime = (pagesQuantity) * (pagesTime)/60
        print("The estimated time to study %s is %s hours" %(subjectName, totalTime) )
        Final_total_time.append(totalTime)


subject()

print(sum(Final_total_time))
```

output:

```
How many subjects do you have to study?2
What is the subject name?Physics
How many pages do you have to study?10
How long do you reckon it will take to study one page (in minutes)?2
The estimated time to study Physics is 0.3333333333333333 hours
What is the subject name?Python
How many pages do you have to study?5
How long do you reckon it will take to study one page (in minutes)?1
The estimated time to study Python is 0.08333333333333333 hours
0.41666666666666663
```